# MySql Equivalent of Sql Server Database Project

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to find a way to put MySql database versioning under source control. In the past, working with SQL Server, I have used the "SQL Server Database Project" project type in Visual Studio.

Is there any way to make that project type work with the MySql .Net Connector?

If not, are there any other ways of creating a MySql database project in .Net?

**UPDATE:**

I found [dbForge](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-projects.html) which has Database Projects in the Professional edition. It's does everything I need it to. Enables us to move the schema into source control, enables us to generate scripts for updating to a new version or rolling back to an old version, etc. The UI is almost an exact duplicate of a visual studio database project.

I'm still going to leave this question open for a while though in case anyone knows of a free alternative.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://dbv.vizuina.com/

Comment: I doubt there's going to be much in Visual Studio for this, but surely there must be database project development tools available for MySQL somewhere?  Isn't there a MySQL Workbench application or something of that nature?  Putting the resulting structure into source control wouldn't be any different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up going with dbForge. It's not free but it works very well.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try Skeema? If you are familiar with Microsoft Dacpac for SQL Server, you will appreciate this tool.

https://github.com/skeema/skeema

You need run two commands.

skeema diff --> To generate the differences.
skeema push --> make changes.

Skeema is documented well.